# How can I can convert a timestamp column format from [YYYY/MM/DD] to from [DD/MM/YYYY] in Python data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, date, timestamp

In a Python data frame, is there a way I can convert a timestamp column with objects formatted as [**YYYY/MM/DD**   HH:MM:SS] to [**DD/MM/YYYY**   HH:MM:SS] instead?

E.g. [2020/01/03  13:00:00] to [03/01/2020  13:00:00]

Where (YYYY is year), (MM is month), (DD is day), (HH is hour), (MM is mins), (SS is seconds).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you expect:

```
import datetime as dt
# Example of df with string for the date
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020/01/03 13:00:00']})
# transforming it in a datetime with a specific format
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
#changing the format as you don't wish
df['colum1'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
#changing the format as you wish
df['colum2'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df
```

OUTPUT :

[image]